# when i run my fitness application it gives : Crashlytics Developer Tools error

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

when i run my fitness application it gives this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'. > Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
```

here is my manifest declaration:

and i don't know how to generate fabric apikey . please help me.

```
 <application
  <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="ApiKey" />
   </application>
```

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.blackcj.fitdata'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        absolutePaths false
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
    }
}

dependencies {       
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.1'
    compile 'nl.qbusict:cupboard:2.1.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

may i hope when i generate key and paste in manifest , it will solve this error but how  to generate fabric apikey i don't know.

All suggestions are welcome. thanks.

Comment: From the [Fabric website](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/api-keys.html): "You can find your key and secret by visiting your organization’s settings page and clicking on the respective links under the organization’s name." I'm guessing you've already registered an account on their website?

Comment: have you first signed up....if not please go through https://www.fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: thanks both..helpful !!

Comment: I'm getting same error with my application but I'm following this documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Comment: I am having the same problem